# Ошибка при работе с Angular: {имя функции} is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, angular4

При возникновении ошибки любого запроса все функции перестают быть функциями. Например, есть сервис для работы с пользователями, у которого есть метод authorizationStatus:

```
authorizationStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this._httpClient.get<boolean>(ApiUrls.authorizationStatus)
    .retry(retryConnectCount)
    .catch(this._logService.handleServerError);
}
```

Если во время запроса происходит ошибка, то функция handleServerError начнет свою работу, но любая функция, вызванная из ее тела, выдаст ошибку. Например если в классе `LogService` будут методы `addError` и `handleServerError`:

```
  public addError(error: string) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  public handleServerError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    this.addError(error.statusText);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
```

То будет получена ошибка

```
this.addError is not a function
```

При том, что `console.error(error);` сработает как нужно. Если закоментировать эту функцию, то выдаст ошибку на следующей функции:

```
error.json is not a function
```

Ошибка появляется при вызове любой нестандартной функции. Как мне решить эту проблему?

Скрин с ошибкой:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так:

```
authorizationStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
    const self = this;
    return this._httpClient.get<boolean>(ApiUrls.authorizationStatus)
        .retry(retryConnectCount)
        .catch(self._logService.handleServerError);
}
```

Comment: это не поможет, так как _внутри_ `handleServerError` `this` будет установлен функцией `catch`

Comment: @Grundy проблема не связана с this (по крайней мере я так думаю). Объект error является вполне нормальным объектом, но его функции тоже вызвать невозможно.

Comment: @mirypoko, ты ошибаешься.